# cant' store PATH after restart bash

Tags: bash, path, mingw

I'm using MINGW64 on Windows 10.
I'd like to use Heroku commands.

If I did `heroku --version`, it says `bash: heroku: command not found`.
So I do `PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/Heroku/bin"`, and heroku commands start to work.

Now, if I close and restart the bash, `heroku --version` still doesn't works.

How can I set the path "forever"? Thanks

Comment: try this https://superuser.com/questions/405342/mingw-bash-profile

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, Windows has the possibility to permanently set environment variables globally via the control panel, but this means that they would apply to all applications, and not only those terminals programs you are going to use for bash.

To do the settings only for bash, you need to understand what happens on bash startup (see the paragraph "INVOCATION" in the bash man page):

If your bash is executed as an interactive login shell, it processes by default the file `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.

If it is interactive, but not a login shell, it processes the files in .bashrc.

If you only run bash as shell, and the topmost shell is started as login shell, you do your PATH settings in .bash_profile and you are done. Since the PATH is exported, it is visible to all child processes.

If you come across the situation, that you start a non-login bash, and there is no bash login-shell among the parent processes, the safe way is to place those definitions into a separate file in your home directory, and source this from both .bash_profile and .bashrc. In this way you ensure that every bash sees these definitions.

Of course you don't want to get your PATH extended again and again by each subsequent child shell, so you need to protect your PATH settings to be applied more than once, for instance by

```
if [[ ${path_extended:-no} == no ]]
then
  export PATH=....
  export path_extended=yes
fi
```

Comment: "but this means that they would apply to all applications, and not only those terminals programs you are going to use for bash." I don't care if all app see heroku. I tried on control panel, but still MINGW doesn't see it. Or at least: I add once, I see first time. When i restart bash, I can't see it anymore. And I need to remove/add again on the control panel.

Comment: @markzzz : What do you mean by _restarting_ bash? If you create a new terminal instance, the variable should be set again correctly - independent of bash (you can verify it with a simple CMD-console). If this is not the case, i.e. if your PATH settings disappear from what you see in the control panel this is a question related to Windows and not to mingw.

Comment: on cmd I see that path. Its on the mingw bash that can't use it. I mean: `heroku --version` works in CMD, not in MINGW64

Comment: Than you have to set up the PATH in the way I suggested in my answer; but what puzzles me: I have never worked with mingw64, but [this page](http://www.mingw.org) suggests that it does not contain a distribution of bash at all, but contains a bourne-like shell called `msys`, so it is unclear to me what bash you are using.